# how to remove calendaritem borders in wpf

Tags: wpf, calendar, border

I am using calendar in WPF and I want to remove the outer white border of it
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTRL.jpg)

I need a calendar ite[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7KxI.jpg)m without borders

Comment: I used the following guide when customizing a calendar control. Not sure if it addresses that white border directly. But it should give you the correct idea on how to customize it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5gMrygW05M

Comment: You have to override the default template for the calendar. [Calendar Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/calendar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: You said the code doesn't work. Please explain exactly how your calendar is styled and templated. How would we reproduce what you are seeing? Please show us the code you tried and sufficient markup etc to reproduce what you are seeing.

Comment: this is the code I have tried:

<Viewbox Width="auto" Height="auto"   >
<Calendar x:Name="MainCalendar" Foreground="Black" Background="{x:null}" Width="auto" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                     FontSize="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" ></Calendar></Viewbox>

Comment: the code below which is doesn't work with me
  private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var borders = FindVisualChildren<Border>(MyCalendar);
        foreach (Border b in borders) 
        { 
            b.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

That calendar looks a bit odd with a grey background so I'm not totally sure what template you're using.

I would first try just setting the calendar border transparent. That seems so obvious maybe you tried it though.

```
          <Calendar BorderBrush="Transparent"
              x:Name="MyCalendar"
              />
```

If that does not work then you could potentially replace the entire template. That could be quite a lot of work if you have a theme.

Alternatively, you could change it in code.

Handle contentrendered or another event where you're sure the calendar will have been rendered.

Brute force iterate through all borders in the calendar setting them transparent:

```
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var borders = FindVisualChildren<Border>(MyCalendar);
        foreach (Border b in borders) 
        { 
            b.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject dO) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (dO == null) yield return (T)Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dO); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject ithChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dO, i);
            if (ithChild == null) continue;
            if (ithChild is T t) yield return t;
            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(ithChild)) yield return childOfChild;
        }
    }
```

I think I might have originally got that findvisualchildren off some post on SO, not sure.

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried the code but it doesn't work with the calender..
how could I replace the entire template?